# MySQL performance: Single query using GROUP_CONCAT, or two separate queries?

Tags: mysql, performance, group-concat

I have a MySQL database in which each user has an account, and each account can have multiple permissions.

My ultimate goal is to end up with the account's username, and a comma-delimited list of permissions ids. There are two ways I can accomplish this:

```
SELECT a.username, GROUP_CONCAT(rp.permission_id) as permission_ids
FROM account AS a
JOIN role_permission AS rp
ON rp.role_id = a.role_id
WHERE a.id = 1902
```

... or ...

```
SELECT username
FROM account
WHERE id = 1902;

SELECT permission_id
FROM account_permission
WHERE account_id = 1902
```

With the single query, I get my results exactly as I want them. With two queries, I have to create the comma-delimited list in the app (PHP) using the second result set.

Are there any performance reasons to NOT choose the first option? I have never used GROUP_CONCAT before, so I don't know the implications of it, performance-wise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The performance should be OK - better than two queries. You need to be aware that the [length is limited](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) though:

> The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the [group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) system variable, which has a default value of 1024. The value can be set higher, although the effective maximum length of the return value is constrained by the value of max_allowed_packet. The syntax to change the value of group_concat_max_len at runtime is as follows, where val is an unsigned integer:

```
SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = val;
```